# Is there an image of ubuntu 23.04 with the old ubiquity installer?

Tags: ubiquity, 23.04

I need to install 23.04 and I'd like to use btrfs with subvolumes and it has to be encrypted. The new installer supports one or the other. I was able to get the setup that I like on the 22.10 installer. I guess I can install 22.10 and then do-release-upgrade to get to 23.04.  Someone told me there was an image? If so can not find it for the life of me.

Answer (score 2):

You can download Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop at this URL

https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

You'll note a large green *Download 23.04* Button, which will download the Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop ISO which uses the `ubuntu-desktop-installer` installer.

Below that is where you click to download the Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop ISO that uses the `ubiquity` installer, ie. the "*Download 23.04 (Legacy Desktop Installer)*" link.

Comment: FYI:   You can scan what ISOs are available are available at https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ , though I don't always find what I'm looking for there too  .. however I find the ISO.QA tracker very helpful - http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/  (*even if I don't use links there, it'll provide naming & other details useful to shorten the searches of cdimage.ubuntu.com  though it'll depend on what ISO you're actually after as to what's best.