# Ubuntu installation creating /boot/efi on the same partition as Windows Boot Manager?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

So I'm installing Ubuntu 23.04 alongside with my Windows 11 (on the same drive). The Ubuntu installation forces `/boot/efi` to be on the same partitions as Windows' (that famous 100mb one). I've read that these are meant to be together, but I'm worried that the 100mb can't handle it.

Is it OK to install it that way? If so, would creating a `/boot` partition for Ubuntu be recommended? (since, as far as I understand it, it would hold the kernels and prevent the 100MB one from filling up)

If not, what can I do?

This is how my drive looks now (with only Windows installed).

[image: img1]

This is what I'm planning.

[image: img2]

Sorry if this is a duplicate, couldn't find one that fits in my case.

Comment: Why is it forced?  You don't have to use the default; you can choose *Something else* and specify what ESP you want to use. I purchased this box earlier this year & it came with windows 11 & its tiny ESP, I added 23.04 & 22.04 as dual-boot and had both use a larger ESP & ignoring the smaller windows one. Only a single ESP can be utilized; my system now ignores the original & tiny ESP. 3 installers are available (selected by ISO) for Ubuntu 23.04 (1 for Server, 2 for Desktop; plus another too if using a *flavor*).

Comment: @guiverc Is there a way to change the `/boot/efi` location though the GUI installer? I'm using the desktop ISO, and I can't find a way to do it :( Another thing, would this make impossible to boot on Windows with grub?

Comment: This is, indeed, the defaault behavior, and I am also not sure why it is forced or what you are worred about. You are forced to breath (try not to :~)), but here, you are free to choose, so nothing is forced.

Comment: For Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop, there are two ISOs. The *default* includes the new `ubuntu-desktop-installer` where as the *alternate* ISO (called *legacy* on the download page) uses the traditional `ubiquity` installer. You didn't say which you are using, but I suspect it's the newer installer. You can make windows impossible to boot (at grub); but I'd only change that post-install and let it offer windows as a boot option (*the default*).

Comment: If you want the *alternate* or *legacy* installer; this question deals with finding it at the [download site](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) for Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1467934/is-there-an-image-of-ubuntu-23-04-with-the-old-ubiquity-installer/1467936#1467936 , but if you select the *Something else* option on either installer, you can install what you want (*as stated earlier; I'd let it include windows option by default in grub, make changes to that after install if required*)

Comment: My Win11 + Ubuntu 22.04 ESP is 37MB total, so 100MB should be fine.  Avoid a separate /boot partition unless you need it (Ancient BIOS, raid, LVM, encryption,...). The EFI partition mounted at /boot/efi contains only bootloaders, not kernels. I don't think you can shuffle things around to save space. If you opt to make a new ESP, do it outside the installer (from the try option) -- the 23.04 (new) installer  makes it difficult to even make a fat partition, let alone an ESP. A fresh install will make its own 1GB ESP if you don't supply one.

Comment: hey guys, thanks for the help! I'm facing another problem rn, the ubuntu installer only boots with safe graphics and is stuck on the "Updates and other software" page. Getting frustrated af. Anyway, Thank you all