# Repeated fresh installations of 23.04 fail to boot after this line

Tags: boot

I've reinstalled 23.04 several times using various USB drives but it consistently fails to boot beyond this:

```
/dev/sda4: recovering journal
/dev/sda4 primary superblock features different from backup, check forced.
CLEARED.
/dev/sda4: 225202/6053888 files (0.5% non-contiguous), 3695315/24204288 blocks
fsck exited with status code 1
[   24.486598] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: download fw command failed (-19)
```

Comment: You didn't give any details as to what Ubuntu 23.04 product (Server, Desktop or *flavor*) nor which ISO/installer (2 options exist for Desktop alone).. but given what I see I'd ignore the Ubuntu part of the question & check the drive health using it's SMART capabilities (*assuming drive is less than 30 years old it'll have it!*) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools   Your provided details reads more as hardware related [to me] though lack of specifics except release detail was provided limiting what I can provide anyway.

Comment: It's the live installer for desktop. I'm also worried it's hardware related. I'll report back after getting home and following your advice. Thank you.

Comment: There are two *live* installers for Ubuntu Desktop 23.04, so which did you download? and thus which installer are you using?  Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop offers two ISOs at download, the the main ISO using the new `ubuntu-desktop-installer` and the *legacy* ISO using the well known `ubiquity` installer (should your hardware have issues with the new installer).  Which did you download?

Comment: This maybe helpful in understanding https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop and the choices of installer/ISOs for Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1467934/is-there-an-image-of-ubuntu-23-04-with-the-old-ubiquity-installer/1467936#1467936   Also note:  If you're using the ISO with `ubuntu-desktop-installer`, you can update the installer prior to starting it, if you have internet available (*on the live session*), which can improve its function  (*I can't recall if updates are available though & won't look*)

Comment: I apologize for the confusion; I had previously heard the two versions in question being referred to in short hand as "Live" and "Legacy" so by "Live" I meant to convey that I did not use legacy. The PC was actually powerful for when it was built, but is now about 10-12 years old other than upgraded RAM. This is the first distribution since all the way back then that wouldn't boot from a fresh installation, but there have been many internal errors even on the clean installations of various Ubuntu installations for the last several years. Would using legacy resolve this?

Comment: Both Desktop ISOs are *live* in operation, the difference being only the installer used on them.  I would try the *alternate* ISO, as it exists for the specific use-case of people who have trouble installing with the newer installer (ie. what you describe!).  Alternatively you could boot your existing ISO, force it to upgrade, then start the install, but that maybe more involved unless you understand what I've just said (ie. know how to upgrade the *snap* packages); but even if that failed, you'd still try the *legacy* ISO using `ubiquity` next.

Comment: I understand and I had already fully upgraded before to no success. I'll try the legacy ISO next and then I'll report back.

Comment: Unfortunately the legacy ISO yielded the same result.