# Installation failed 23.10 subiquity 1267

Tags: boot, system-installation, 23.10

Trying to install 23.10 on a 2009 iMac 10.1. I have already wiped the hard drive with Apple's disk utility. I start the process for Ubuntu install and I can get through all of the options. It shows that the system is being installed and sits like that for like 10 minutes. After that it says it failed:

```
/snap/ubuntu-desktop-installer/1267/bin/subiquity/subiquity/cmd/server.py

Problem type: Bug
Title: install failed crashed with CalledProcessError
```

I made sure it was a clean flash of the image on the USB. It allows the "Try Ubuntu" still so I can still navigate and do everything. iIt just won't install.

Comment: You aren't clear with what 23.10 product, but I note `ubuntu-desktop-installer` which implies a desktop system; have you tried the *legacy* installer? (ie. `ubiquity`).   It's about the same as prior release; ie. this page maybe helpful - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1467934/is-there-an-image-of-ubuntu-23-04-with-the-old-ubiquity-installer/1467936#1467936  as the other alternative is exploring system log files for clues

Comment: Does your hashcheck match the published one?  That said, tonight I noticed my hashchecked Ubuntu 23.10.1 would run as "Try", but would hang in installing to a VM.  I'd had no trouble with the earlier beta release.  I second trying the legacy installer mentioned above.